# Apple Sign In Not Working in Flutter Android App

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I have almost tried all the solutions present on github and stack overflow and double checked my code and procedure while integrating this sign in feature for my flutter android app but nothing works so far. I have also tried the dummy glitch server which is present mentioned in their document in [this link](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple), but this thing doesn't work for android as well whenever I tried to sign in using my apple id this plugin doesn't redirects back to my flutter app but stucks on this error after signing in successfully.  Here is my code which I am using for signing in:

```
    Future appleLogin() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      final rawNonce = generatingAEncryptionKey();
      final nonce = generatingSHA256Key(rawNonce);
      final appleUser = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
        webAuthenticationOptions: WebAuthenticationOptions(
          // TODO: Set the `clientId` and `redirectUri` arguments to the values you entered in the Apple Developer portal during the setup
          clientId: 'com.digidots.full-match',

          redirectUri: Uri.parse('https://locrian-tin-polka.glitch.me/callbacks/sign_in_with_apple'),
        ),
        nonce: nonce,
      );
      print("dataOf apple:-=-=-=-=- $appleUser");
      var payload = {
        'email': appleUser.email,
        'name': appleUser.givenName,
        'provider_id': appleUser.identityToken,
        'devicetype': Platform.isIOS ? 'ios' : 'android',
        'devicetoken': prefs.getString('device_token'),
      };
      flushBar('Please wait...');
      socialLogin(payload);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  String generatingAEncryptionKey([int length = 32]) {
    final charset =
        '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._';
    final random = Random.secure();
    return List.generate(length, (_) => charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)])
        .join();
  }

  /// Returns the sha256 hash of [input] in hex notation.
  String generatingSHA256Key(String input) {
    final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
    final digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return digest.toString();
  }
```

And here are screenshots of my error

The code above redirects my app to the apple signing in link

[image]

After signing in successfully it requests my permission to share the information

[image]

After pressing continue button it redirects me to link:

```
intent://callback?code=c4f89bed93fa0476982c1d17549ac3231.0.rrzrr.q3kBNYdzaM6lO84iXNmEfQ&id_token=eyJraWQiOiJlWGF1bm1MIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLmRpZ2lkb3RzLmZ1bGwtbWF0Y2giLCJleHAiOjE2MTUxMTc3NjEsImlhdCI6MTYxNTAzMTM2MSwic3ViIjoiMDAxOTExLjhkNDBiYWRmZjJkZDRjYWI4ODc3ZmJjYjY5YmNiNDQ5LjA4NDIiLCJub25jZSI6IjMyNjM5OWJmNGQ2NjVhMDc3MWY1ZjI3MzVmOTVmMDNhMzk2NDYwODVkMTViZDY2MmY0ZGFjZjNhNzlkMjAyNzAiLCJjX2hhc2giOiJubWcyMmdBMEpBZjJYRVBXRmNUVVNnIiwiZW1haWwiOiJoYW16YWJpbGFsZ2F5YUBob3RtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjoidHJ1ZSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTYxNTAzMTM2MSwibm9uY2Vfc3VwcG9ydGVkIjp0cnVlfQ.Smbuymx1Kk5oPXdRDnYWtJiqN7K6PLjyOsRaBgePg7H-_eWcO4F9bVi1UhTOaPK4HZ8fSk2PJ5hVBCyCsj0BhxJDMpn6Ne3MYnOZKHdWV6THYfKgnYLT7FDCePlpYZnZG9dhrhaK9HVw6Rvcfx0kEyNlNG6GZbAhb9DgfeZeGOIpdPMP0fjYmm8tdjqjRbBg-1VrRuV2wnyt0pzhrU8qvHsJVJHHCqO2WaN5lMXAMPCQJu1mZflL8HD0WnNOX8Lve-rEf4VEIRLVACRvSes6Qgkl5Lbnd2GKCk838Xk-N_VpgYCU7-Lmgn0HsSMFNuy1UI1I7xpr-b2cYD8ReHiO0w#Intent;package=com.digidots.full_match_app;scheme=signinwithapple;end
```

However it's main purpose is to redirect me back to my app again but it doesn't and the link results in below error

[image]

Comment: Do you find any solutions?